# How to diagnose what is blocking the installation of Linux package?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, firmware

[Detailed answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/745231/26026)

---

I am trying to install the package Debian `firmware-misc-nonfree` on a particular Linux installation.

```
╰─○ apt install firmware-misc-nonfree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package firmware-misc-nonfree is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'firmware-misc-nonfree' has no installation candidate
```

And something seems to be holding it back, yet on two other systems it is fine.

This is the output of `apt-cache policy`

```
╰─○ apt-cache policy firmware-misc-nonfree
firmware-misc-nonfree:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     20210315-3 -1
         -1 http://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/debian bullseye/non-free amd64 Packages
```

Is there some way automated way to find the cause of the conflict?

These are the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# updated 2023-03-11-1956 for Debian 11 Bullseye

deb http://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free

# bullseye-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

# deb http://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/debian/ bullseye-backports main contrib non-free
# deb-src http://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/debian/ bullseye-backports main contrib non-free
```

The only thing I can think of is that this installation os a VirtualBox system and that the virtualization may have something to do with it.

It needs some binary firmware which is not in the proper directory, but I can copy it from the other systems into its proper place where it can be loaded at boot time.

Does the Debian packaging system maintain a log of the commands issued when the installation of a package triggers a hold, the removal or block of another?

I have tried some of the suggestions at https://askubuntu.com/questions/640986/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-packages-held-back-from-upgrade but the commands don't show anything.

Comment: As the error message shows, you can't install that package because it no longer exists.

Comment: @Shadur The  package exists - https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-misc-nonfree. My  other Debian 11 installations  can install  it.

Comment: Ah, right. You'll want to add the `non-free-firmware` category to the list of `main contrib non-free`. There was a discussion about this on the debian mailing list

Comment: Still waking up; I'll write a more formal answer when I get to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-cache policy firmware-misc-nonfree` shows the package is available with priority -1. -1 prevents it to be selected as candidate among multiple candidates (even if it's the only candidate). From [`apt_preferences(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/apt/apt_preferences.5#How_APT_Interprets_Priorities):

> How APT Interprets Priorities
>
> [...]
>
> P < 0
>
> prevents the version from being installed

You can still override the setting by stating a candidate version yourself. For example this should install the package:

```
apt-get install firmware-misc-nonfree=20210315-3
```

Chances are some settings about apt's preferences were changed. The first places to look would be `/etc/apt/preferences` or in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`.

Comment: I checked the `/etc/apt/preferences.d` directory and found a `non_free_policy` file which has the `Pin-priority: - 1`. Some other process may have changed it, and I suspect that VirtualBox changes some settings to avoid problems with the hosts settings.

Answer (score 1):

The package firmware-misc-nonfree can be downloaded from: https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/firmware-misc-nonfree/download. That the latest. If you want the older bullseye package, use:
https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/all/firmware-misc-nonfree/download.

It can be installed with: dpkg -i .

If you run: apt-file list firmware-misc-nonfree, it will show all the files in the package and their locations under the /lib/firmware directory.

The /var/log/apt directory holds the history of apt activity.

Answer (score 1):

What happened is that Debian has moved various bits of non-free firmware into its own repository tree, separate from `non-free`, because several of those are unfortunately too vital for a lot of modern systems, especially laptops, to omit by default.

Update your sources as follows:

```
deb http://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free
```

to

```
deb http://uk.mirrors.clouvider.net/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

and you should see the package again.

Comment: After adding the `non-free-firmware` source `apt-update` produces a lot of  errors such as `W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free-firmware/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the component 'non-free-firmware' (component misspelt in sources.list?)`.

I suspect the problem must still be something in the configuration. The `non-free-firmware` option must be for bookworm, so I suppose I must add a separate entry for `non-free-firmware` pointing to `bookworm`

Answer (score 0):

After following the suggestions in the [selected answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743558/26026) I discovered that `/etc/apt/preferences.d` directory had the file `non_free_policy` which had the contents:

```
Explanation: Disable packages from non-free tree by default
Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,a=stable,l=Debian,c=non-free
Pin-Priority: -1
```

It seems the Debian installer sets this priority for `non-free` packages by default, and it is probably why I have had to compile more than few wireless and bluetooth drivers in the past.

I wonder how many users have fallen foul of this setting over the years without knowing.